# JS code stops when I jump to another page

Tags: javascript, css, web

I'm trying to get this to work:

```
window.location.href='tsa.html#tile4';
document.body.scrollTop -= 100;
```

It is trying to jump to a new page at a certain position then scroll up a bit.
But it seems the second half doesn't work because the browser jumps away.
Any simple fixes?

Comment: Did you try switching the order?

Comment: No because then it just scrolls up into the current page before jumping to the next one.

Answer (score 0):

When you change to another page, the current document is unloaded and all JS in it stops executing.  A new document loads and the JS in it starts running.

Comment: Yes I got that the JS discontinued because a new document loaded.

Comment: @user2483724 - then you need JS in the new page to position it as desired when it loads.  Or, you could use an `<a name="tile4"></a>` tag in the new page and the hash value in the URL will automatically scroll to it.

Comment: I have something like "location.hash == '#tile4'" checking on load and  print statement inside the block works, but document.body.scrollTop -= 100 doesn't. I've even tried replacing that with jQuery. I just jump to #tile4 and then nothing happens

Comment: If scrollTop is less than 0, then it is just set to 0.  Are you sure you want to be doing `-=` and not `+=`?  See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollTop).

Comment: Yeah, I need it to go up a bit because of a fixed header blocking a portion. I also tried it with += but still no reaction.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions. First one is you don't reload pages, but get them in ajax requests and override body contents. Then, you may have your scripts working non-stop.

But for you, it would be easier to move second line (about scroll) to script in page `tsa.html`. For example, (jquery)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if (location.hash == '#tile4')
            document.body.scrollTop -= 100
    })
</script>
```

Without jquery, look for some `<body onload>` event handling.

Comment: The second option seems the way to go, I have a print "hello" working inside the if statement but nothing happens with the document.body.scrollTop

Comment: Ok, try to do it like that: `setTimeout('$(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop()-100)', 100)`

Comment: @user2483724 It would postpone the scrolling a bit, to invoke it after page scrolls itself to an anchor.

Comment: Still doesn't work, though if it did it would seem really confusing. I guess it's just some weird thing with the setup I have...

Answer (score 0):

I've found something that works, though I still don't know why the other proposed solutions
don't work:

```
$('html, body').animate({ 
    scrollTop: $('#tile4').offset().top - 100
}, 'fast');
```

There is still an annoying animation though.